# Why is my function returning a wrong value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, pycharm

I just started learning Python recently. I cannot figure out the reason why my function is returning the wrong value. Basically, I want to calculate the total number of even numbers in a list.

Codes in myModule.py

```
def evenNum(x):
    e_count = 0
    for num in x:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            e_count += 1
            return e_count
```

Codes in main.py

```
import sys
import myModule

inputList = [int(s) for s in sys.argv[1].split(',')]
    
print("no. of even numbers is:%d"%(myModule.evenNum(inputList)))
```

Output in cmd

```
C:\Users\belle\Testing\Exercise1> main.py 14,12,9,21,23,2
 no. of even numbers is:1
```

The result should be 3 instead of 1...

Comment: Did you mean to return after the `for num in x` loop? Right now you return right after you run `e_count += 1` for the first time. If so, then you just have to unindent the `return` twice.

Comment: @RandomDavis thank you so much! it works. I was unaware of the indentation rule for the 'return'.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I can't think of any keywords or values in python not subject to indentation in order to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation. The previous version would just return 1 once it found an even value and `None` if `x` didn't have any.

```py
def evenNum(x):
    e_count = 0
    for num in x:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            e_count += 1
    return e_count
```

Comment: thank you so much! it works. I was unaware of the indentation rule for the 'return' as I just started learning recently.

Comment: @BellaSwan it's not a rule specific to returns, Python uses indentation to know which statement to run next; if there's another statement at the current indentation level, it'll run that next.